# Can you create videos using SVGs?

Tags: animation, svg

I have always looked for a tool that can create videos [like these](https://www.umotif.com/) (see second section, the overview)

These tools are normally used on the videos for startups, and if I'm not wrong, the graphics shown are all SVGs.

I'm preferably looking for an Open Source program. **What software is used to make videos/animations with SVGs?**

Comment: This is a two part question.  1) What software to use to generate an `.svg`. 2) What video production software can I use to make a video reel with `.svg` files.  Please disclose what you have tried so we can provide the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is an image format, however it is also output as XML code, so it can be animated using CSS. There are many examples online of these kind of animations, but your linked example is not one of them.

The video you linked to however, looks like a normal video with vector animations. This is easily accomplished in After Effects, but could be done in many other tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is a video my brother and I made using animated SVG.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cul1CAh_Pio

The characters were designed by Dave using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), and animated using [Synfig](https://www.synfig.org/).  We arranged the scenes using [KdenLive](https://kdenlive.org/en/).

we rigged up a python script that allowed the project to be built using Continuous Integration techniques through [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

Our project used to be hosted on Bazaar - but is now on github :

https://github.com/computamike/scargo